# How is this a histogram?

Tags: statistics

[image]

I am so confused, I have never seen a histogram represented like any of these before.

In the book it says that for cumulative relative frequency plots:

if distribution is skewed to the left then the cumulative frequency plot rises slowly at first and then steeply later but a distribution skewed to the right has a cumulative frequency plot which rises steeply at first and then slowly later.

I just don't know how this is a histogram or what I am supposed to do.

Comment: What would the definite integral of the four histograms look like? Two of the four should resemble the two graphs in question.

Comment: well first im confused because i dont understand how this is even a histogram. and as for the definite integral, i think that A corresponds to the second question and because in the cumulative relative frequency table, the median is also the point of concavity and A corresponds to that. and i associated D to the first question. but i havent been introduced to integrals in my ap stats class, that's why i am confused even more

Comment: actually wait i think i understand now. for the first question i think it is C because C starts out with a lot of area under the curve and then there is less. then for the second question the answer is A because A starts out with little area under the curve and gets bigger then reaches its climax, after which the area under the curve is getting smaller. the larger areas represent the steeper parts of the crf graph is and the smaller areas represent the more gradual areas of the crf plot. is my logic correct?

Comment: i still am so confused about how this is a histogram though

Comment: 'Histogram' is odd terminology here. 'Density function' would have been better. And I believe you are correct in choices of C and A, respectively.